# Spring Data JPA - Is it possible to update an entity with principal before persisting it inside a repository?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I would like to secure my Resource Server with Spring Security 5 to be usable for many users. I have an entity `Task` which contains a field `userId`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
data class Task(
    @NotBlank
    val name: String,

    val description: String?,

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "task_id_seq")
    val id: Long = 0,

    @UUID //custom validation annotation
    val userId: String? = null
)
```

I found a method to use SpEL to inject JWT principal inside query. What I have already done is I have overridden `findAll()` method in my `interface TaskRepository : JpaRepository<Task, Long>` with `@Query` annotation:

```
@Query("select t from Task t where t.userId = :#{principal.claims['sub']}")
//sub is a userId in OpenID Connect 1.0, claim is a Map<String, Object>
override fun findAll(): List<Task>
```

The problem is that i would like to do something similar with `save()` method. The only thing I have found is to do an update on already saved entity. I created a completely new method:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Task t set t.userId = :#{principal.claims['sub']} where t.id = :id")
fun setUserId(@Param("id") id: Long)
```

but the problem is that I need to call this method in my TaskService, what looks like this:

```
@Transactional
fun createTask(taskDto: CreateTaskDto): Task {
    val task = taskRepository.save(taskDto.toEntity())
    taskRepository.setUserId(task.id)
    return task
}
```

Is it possible to add this information automatically every time I save an entity in my database? Then my code inside TaskService would look like this:

```
@Transactional
fun createTask(taskDto: CreateTaskDto): Task {
    return taskRepository.save(taskDto.toEntity())
}
```

Comment: Why not injecting the Principal/Authentication in the RestController and provide it to the service, and let the service handle the authentication?

Comment: This is the simplest but most annoying solution for this problem. Every endpoint would need to add Principal as a parameter and it's needed to pass further. Second, I would need to use some Util class everywhere to get userId. When I do this on JpaRepository level, I think this is the most elegant solution and most appropriate, because I'm dealing with authorization granting on data level. Service and RestController does not know anything about a user and code is much cleaner.

Comment: i like clear and understandable code even if writing is annoying ;-)

Comment: Do you suggest that in your opinion my solution is less clear than passing every time Principal inside service methods?

Comment: At least i suggest that "annoying" is no argument for a solution to be good or bad. In my case I pass the principal every time into the service methods, cause if you read the method you know about authentication, the data layer therefore is pretty stupid  .. on the other hand is the auditing feature something i don't know yet, after reading it looks pretty usefull. But you have to know about that - and this might be some risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple, but I didn't know what am I was looking for. Still, I do not know if this is a canonical solution. I use Jpa Auditing for this. First, I added `@CreatedBy` annotation to the field I wanted to be updated before an insertion inside my entity. The entity class I also annotated with `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)`. Note that it was needed to change `val` keyword to `var` (from `final` field to non-final field in Java world).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
data class Task(
        @NotBlank
        val name: String,

        val description: String?,

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "task_id_seq")
        val id: Long = 0,

        @UUID
        @CreatedBy
        var userId: String? = null
    )
```

The next step was to implement `interface AuditorAware<T>` and make it visible for Spring by using @Component (or creating a bean inside config class)

```
@Component
class SpringSecurityAuditorAware : AuditorAware<String> {

    override fun getCurrentAuditor(): Optional<String> {
        return Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()?.authentication)
                .filter { authentication -> authentication.isAuthenticated }
                .map { authentication -> authentication.principal as Jwt }
                .map { jwt -> jwt.claims["sub"] as String? }
    }

}
```

Last, but not least, was adding a @EnableJpaAuditing on some Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
class ResourceServerContext
```